# How do I get the QDrag hotspot value in the dropEvent function?

Tags: qt

I'm somewhat new to Qt, and I'm using Qt 4.8 to implement a graphical editor of sorts. Right now I've implemented dragging of rectangles around my widget using drag&drop. In my mousePressEvent function I generate a QDrag with appropriate MIME data (similar to the puzzle sample), and I just added a 'setHotSpot' call.

The dragging works just fine, but in my dropEvent function, I can't figure out a way to get back to the hot-spot setting in the original QDrag object - I don't appear to have access to it.

I've solved it for the moment by stuffing the hot-spot point into my MIME data (it's custom data anyway), but that seems wrong to me - it seems to me that there'd be some way within the Qt framework for me to get that hot-spot data in my dropEvent function.

Comment: please add some code....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check the following example in Qt.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-draganddrop-fridgemagnets-example.html

this example shows how to use drag an drop events in Qt.

In that example we see that adding the hot-spot's point to the MIME data does in fact appear to be the recommended way to get the hot-spot point from where the drag is initiated do the dropEvent.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you are trying to achieve...

The "hotspot" point is just an offset point relative to the pixmap representing the data being dragged, and thus is constant during the whole drag.

If you are looking for the initial drag point, you should indeed encode it into the mime data.

Comment: That was the question - the initial drag point (which I need to factor in when doing the drop). Encoding the initial drag point into the mime data (which is what I did) just didn't seem in keeping with how Qt does things, so I thought I missed something.